# What's the difference between the "MVC" and "Single Page Application" templates?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Creating a new MVC5 project, what should I know before choosing between the two templates: "MVC" and "Single Page Application"? What are the key differences?

[image]

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#vs2013) for an explanation of Visual Studio 2013 Web Project Templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have not provided enough information for a full assessment, most likely you want to use the regular MVC Template.

**MVC Template**

- ASP.NET MVC was designed to facilitate patterns-based development
  practices such as test-driven development, separation of concerns,
  inversion of control, and dependency injection. The framework
  encourages separating the business logic layer of a web application
  from its presentation layer. By dividing the application into models
  (M), views (V), and controllers (C), ASP.NET MVC can make it easier
  to manage complexity in larger applications.

**Single Page Application Template**

- The Single Page Application (SPA) template creates a sample
  application that uses JavaScript, HTML 5, and KnockoutJS on the
  client, and ASP.NET Web API on the server.

So the choice is quite easy. Unless you are planning to build a SPA using KnockoutJS, go with the regular template.

Comment: I just stick with the regular MVC template then.